# Cannot reach JSON Result (coming from WCF) from Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

Just starting to use Retrofit, but I have a few doubts. I can´t avoid a few errors which don´t let me debug my app. So sorry for bother you all.

Well, this is the part of the code which maybe you need to know.

As you all see, **Graddle**, **Interface** (for Rest), **Pojo** **Class** (with class and parent class which is a list of the first one), and the **activity** (I call retrofit in *onCreate*, and I recover Data in *onResponse*)

```
--Graddle--
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'

--Pojo--
public class pisoAlquiler {
private int codigo;
private String fotos;
}

public class pisosAlquiler {
List<pisoAlquiler> pisoAlquilerList;
}

--Interface--
public interface RestApi {
@GET("/Service1.svc?wsdl")
Call<pisosAlquiler> devolverPisosA();
}

--Activity--
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alquiler);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:52896")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    // prepare call in Retrofit 2.0
    RestApi restApi = retrofit.create(RestApi.class);

    Call<pisosAlquiler> call = restApi.devolverPisosA();
    //asynchronous call
    call.enqueue(this);
}

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<pisoAlquiler> call, Response<pisoAlquiler> response) {
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    // Create a LinearLayout element
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    pisosAlquiler prueba = (pisosAlquiler) response.body().pisoAlquilerList;
}
```

I´m getting two errors, problably coming from the same issue.

In **onCreate**:

```
call.enqueue(this);
```

*this* returns error saying *in Call cannot be applied*, if I use pisoAlquiler Class, instead of pisosAlquiler (which contains a list of pisoAlquiler) the error dissapear.

In **onResponse**:

```
pisosAlquiler prueba = (pisosAlquiler) response.body().pisoAlquilerList;
```

*pisoAlquilerList* returns *cannot resolve symbol*. Looks like I can call attributes of pisoAlquiler but not the only attribute which pisosAlquiler has it...

Any Ideas?

Thanks Mates.

Comment: change `pisosAlquiler prueba = (pisosAlquiler) response.body().pisoAlquilerList`; to this : `pisosAlquiler prueba = (pisosAlquiler) response.body();`. Remember also that according to your POJO - pisoAlquilerList is private - so might not be accessible to the call `.pisoAlquilerList`.

Comment: When you call `call.enqueue(this);` - is your current class (`this`) implementing `Callback<pisoAlquiler>`  OR does it implement `Callback<pisosAlquiler>`?

Comment: You can see my working answers :

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098347/how-to-use-gson-2-0-on-onresponse-from-retrofit-2-0/37099604#37099604
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771946/error-when-using-retrofit/36773538#36773538

Comment: ishmael... It as that. I forgot I changed Callback<pisoAlquiler> to Callback<pisosAlquiler>. Everything is worked. Cool!!
Anyway, Why don´t you post an answer? I would like reward to efford and rate it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

The problem was I´m in Debbug Mode and WCF (by Visual Studio) and Android Studio wasn´t configurated in the same network.

For configuring Visual Studio for working with Android Studio in a Local Network, following the next:

**Web.Config** must to be set for listening from differents places. Between services and Behavior tags:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

Open **applicationhost.config** allocated in Project Folder --> Config:
Change the next one:

```
<site name="Proyect" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\ProjectFolder\Proyect />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52896:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

For:

```
<site name="Proyect" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\ProjectFolder\Proyect" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52896:localhost" />
              <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52896:*" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

With this, We can listen internal request.

Open Windows Firewall for that port.